# Embedded Cassandra doesn't support the MacOS M1 chip

Tags: java, cassandra, embedded-cassandra

I've followed the instructure of this guide: https://nosan.github.io/embedded-cassandra/4.0.7/#what-are-oss-supported-by-embedded-cassandra.
I faced with the issue that library doesn't support the m1 aarch64 chip. I used the:

- AmazonCorretto OpenJdk 1.8
- Maven builder manager
- Macbook pro 14 m1 chip

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>CassandraTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.nosan</groupId>
        <artifactId>embedded-cassandra</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Main.java

```
package org.example;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Cassandra;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.CassandraBuilder;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.Settings;
import com.github.nosan.embedded.cassandra.cql.CqlScript;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cassandra cassandra = new CassandraBuilder()
                .addJvmOptions("-Xmx1024m", "-Xms1024m", "-Xss700k")
                .build();

        cassandra.start();
        try {
            Settings settings = cassandra.getSettings();
            try (CqlSession session = CqlSession.builder()
                    .addContactPoint(new InetSocketAddress(settings.getAddress(), settings.getPort()))
                    .withLocalDatacenter("datacenter1")
                    .build()) {
                CqlScript.ofClassPath("schema.cql").forEachStatement(session::execute);
            }
        }
        finally {
            cassandra.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
ERROR [main] 2023-11-16 15:23:50,249 NativeLibraryDarwin.java:64 - Failed to link the C library against JNA. Native methods will be unavailable.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/pavlo/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna5079777972566874879.tmp: dlopen(/Users/pavlo/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna5079777972566874879.tmp, 0x0001): tried: '/Users/pavlo/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna5079777972566874879.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/pavlo/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna5079777972566874879.tmp' (no such file), '/Users/pavlo/Library/Caches/JNA/temp/jna5079777972566874879.tmp' (fat file, but missing compatible architecture (have 'i386,x86_64', need 'arm64'))
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1934)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1817)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:782)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1100)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibraryFromClasspath(Native.java:1018)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeDispatchLibrary(Native.java:988)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:195)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:87)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibraryDarwin.<clinit>(NativeLibraryDarwin.java:55)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:98)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:258)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:765)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:889)
```

Answer (score 2):

it should work right now, it was Apache Cassandra limitation.
You can try embedded-cassandra 4.1.0